# Android:StretchColumns: Correct arguments?

Tags: android, tablelayout

For the following code:

```
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="2" >
```

Does  `android:stretchColumns="2"` mean that the 3 columns are stretchable, or that column 3 is stretchable?

Answer (score 0):

**A TableLayout can specify certain columns as shrinkable or stretchable
by calling setColumnShrinkable() or setColumnStretchable(). If marked as shrinkable, the column width can be shrunk to fit the table into its parent object. If marked as stretchable, it can expand in width to fit any extra space. The total width of the table is defined by its parent container.**

Have a look here, keep in mind that if your table fits nicely ( no space left to stretch) in the parent object, you would not see any changes no matter what value you put in.

Comment: This doesnt answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

If u want to stretch all Columns u should use android:stretchColumns="*" it works also to android:shrinkColumns.

And this pro tutorial should explain all yours issues 
http://www.onlinevideolecture.com/computer-programming/slidenerd/android-programming-course-android-tutorials-for-beginners/index.php?course_id=2369&lecture_no=59

android:stretchColumns="1" will stretch column 1
android:stretchColumns="0,1" will stretch columns 1 and 0.